# networkmanager with gnome 3.6.2 in Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, gnome3, networkmanager

Every `networkmanager` I've tried is "incompatible with this version" in gnome's settings panel. I can still connect from command line fine, but that's just kind of a pain.

**Solutions I have tried:**

- `pacman -Syu networkmanager` installed everything fine, but didn't solve the problem.
- `pacman -S gnome-extra` installed everything fine, but didn't solve the problem.
- `pacman -S gnome-network-manager`: pacman says "package not found" (the package is outdated according to wiki)
- `pacman -S network-manager-applet`  installed everything fine, but didn't solve the problem.

The arch wiki says `network-manager-applet` [should suffice for gnome](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network-manager#GNOME), but the GUI won't support it, which is inconvenient. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by saying that "installed everything fine, but didn't solve"? How does it not work after you did that? And I know that this question has been asked a long time ago, and it may have an solution already, but if it doesn't have an solution, you should update your whole system by doing `pacman -Syu`, which will update gnome too. Then it will probably work.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is actually really easy to solve, although I can't blame you for not finding the solution - it isn't very clearly mentioned on the wiki.

The problem is that even if you've installed NetworkManager, the daemon does not run by default. To fix this:

```
sudo systemctl enable NetworkManager.service
sudo systemctl start NetworkManager.service
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pacman -Ss` to search for packages and `pacman -Syu` to install packages.

To learn about what the switches do in `pacman` you can use `pacman -h`. This will output all the main (capital letter) switches such as `-S -V -D -Q -R -S -T -U`. Each one of these also has switches that you can use, to find out what those are and how they work use `pacman -Xh` (replacing X with the main switch of your choice).

Also, try to post the *exact* errors that you're getting so we can get a better understanding as to what's going on. There are also a few of other network managing tools available such as `wicd`.

Take a look at [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager#Graphical_front-ends) page on the Arch Linux Wiki. Should clear up any issue you're having.